# How do I get the row count of conditional value in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Dataframe

```
     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 .... 1000

aa | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 7 |...| 1

bb | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 |...| 0

cc | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |...| 1

dd | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |...| 0
.
.
.

zz | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |...| 0
```

I have tried using :

```
DFcount = DF1.apply(lambda x: True if x.any() > 0 else  False,axis=1)
numOfRows = len(DFcount[DFcount == True].index)
```

I also tried using :

```
DFcount = DF1.apply(lambda x: True if x.all() > 0 else  False,axis=1)
numOfRows = len(DFcount[DFcount == True].index)
```

But the output is not what i expected

The output should be the **sum of all column** which has **value > 0** in all row.

```
aa 100

bb 23

cc 56

dd 12
.
.
.

zz 5
```

and descendingly sorted as follows :

```
aa 100

mm 98

cc 56

bb 23

dd 12
.
.
.

zz 5
```

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data from question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df.gt(0).sum(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False).rename_axis('a').reset_index(name='b')

print (df1)
    a  b
0  cc  4
1  zz  2
2  dd  2
3  aa  2
4  bb  1
```

**Explanation**:

First compare by `0` all values with [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) (`>`):

```
print (df.gt(0))
        0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8   1000
aa  False  False  False  False  False   True  False  False  False   True
bb  False   True  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
cc  False   True   True  False  False   True  False  False  False   True
dd  False  False  False  False  False   True  False   True  False  False
zz  False  False   True  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
```

Then sum `True`s (processed like `1`) values per rows:

```
print (df.gt(0).sum(axis=1))
aa    2
bb    1
cc    4
dd    2
zz    2
dtype: int64
```

And then sorting by [`Series.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html):

```
print (df.gt(0).sum(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False))
cc    4
zz    2
dd    2
aa    2
bb    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The value is not only 0 and 1, as i explained above i want to count/sum all the column which has value > 1. And also aa bb cc dd is already as index. So there is no 0 1 2 3 4 as your answer mentioned

Comment: @FH337 - Sure, second solution was removed

Comment: Well i tried to simplify it, and this piece of code will do it all :                                  
    df1 = df.gt(0).sum(axis=1).sort_values(ascending=False)

Comment: @FH337 - Super. Also added explanation to answer.